# Remove automatically new row from DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

When new row added in DataGrid wheter empty or wrong data it's kept added. 
How can I test if causes exception in order to remove it ?

- I'm using MVVM and PRISM
- The DataGrid is bound to an `ObservableCollection<Humain>`

  **EDIT** : here are pics
   pic1 : Default empty row is double clicked. 
   pic2 : Data insertion is canceled by click anywhere else.

[image: When double click on the empty row to start adding new data]
[image: Here when edit is canceled by clicking somewhere else]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since you don't have any code to show us what your Rows look like, or how you are editing them, this general answer is the best I can do:

- Subscribe to the [CollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653375%28v=vs.95%29) event. The new row will be in the args.
- Check each property for what you consider "emptiness" (assuming you have something other than strings). Return if you find a non-empty property. Otherwise, delete the row.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Since you asked for more detail on how editing, here I added 2 pics with descriptions.

Comment: @HichemC I am guessing by this structure that `Name` is the only thing you are checking for emptiness?

Comment: I tried using CollectionChanged event but this one is unfortunately not fired when editing is canceled (pic2)

Comment: @HichemC If editing is cancelled, then it shouldn't add a row... Whats the problem?

Comment: My issue is not on what data has to be checked but how to remove that spare row when emptiness condition is raised

Comment: I still don't know if the idea is clear or not : in pic1 I just double clicked and then clicked on the previous row, what I want is by clicking on the previous row or anywhere else the added row get dropped.

Comment: @HichemC So its not adding a row to the observable collection, its just leaving it on the datagrid?

Comment: Exactly, everything is happening on the view

Comment: I just tried this, and cancelling the edit cleared the row. I am not using PRISM, and I am not sure what your code looks like, so I just made a very simple datagrid bound to a collection, but it worked fine. Please post your code.

Comment: Please put your code snippet so i can mark it as an answer. it still doesn't work for me